# Fetch API Post method is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, cors, fetch-api, preflight

```
fetch('http://localhost:9000/api/app/contact', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        email: this.state.email,
        contactNumber: this.state.phone,
        enquiry: this.state.msg
    })
})
.then(function(res) { return res.json() })
.then(function(data) {
    alert('We will contact you shortly') 
});
```

When I render above coding, I've encountered following error:

> Failed to load http://localhost:9000/api/app/contact: Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed
>   access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
>   mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

But when I tried with postman, it's successfully working. Please help me, is there any code missing in my fetch api.

Following is postman POST request and code.

[image]

following code is Post request from `Postman`.

```
var data = JSON.stringify({
  "email": "test@gmail.com",
  "contactNumber": "0123456789",
  "enquiry": "Testing"
});

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = true;

xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
  if (this.readyState === 4) {
    console.log(this.responseText);
  }
});

xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:9000/api/app/contact");
xhr.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/json");
xhr.setRequestHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
xhr.setRequestHeader("postman-token", "d5e08b69-5f0f-8193-e021-e2c3b1bfe1a3");

xhr.send(data);
```

In NodeJS server side, I've already CORS in backend.

```
var express = require('express'),
    controller = require('./app.controller'),
    router = express.Router(),
    cors = require('cors');

var issue2options = {
  origin: true,
  methods: ['POST'],
  credentials: true,
  maxAge: 3600
};

router.post('/contact', cors(issue2options), controller.sendContactForm);
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: CORS support needs to be added/enabled on the server running on `http://localhost:9000`. See https://enable-cors.org/server.html and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: @sideshowbarker I've edited my answer and configured CORS in node.

Comment: Am I reading in your code correctly that on the node server you only have CORS enabled for the `/contact` route but that your frontend code is making a request to `/api/app/contact`? On the node backend do those somehow end up resolving to the same route? To isolate/troubleshoot the problme, Have you tried testing with temporarily enabling CORS for all routes instead of just that one route?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add explicit `OPTIONS` handling for [CORS preflights](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests) that browsers send on their own:

```
app.options('/contact', cors(issue2options)); // enable preflight OPTIONS
router.post('/contact', cors(issue2options), controller.sendContactForm);
```

See https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#enabling-cors-pre-flight

Answer (score 1):

Postman is not the same as the browser.

To fix that, you need the server in 
 `http://localhost:9000/api/app/contact` to return in its headers the CORS header, like this for example `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

Read here for detailed CORS reference https://enable-cors.org/server.html

Comment: I've edited my answer and CORS is already configured in NodeJS.